# Taylor approximation for $\ln(1.3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have to calculate an approximation for $\ln(1.3)$ using degree $2$ expansion for Taylor polynomial:

$$P_2(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2$$

So I can take $x_0 = 1$ and $x = 1.3$ right?

Then I get

$$P_2(1.3) = \ln(1) + \frac{1}{1}(1.3-1) - \frac{1}{1^2}(1.3-1)^2$$

which gives me $0.21$, but my book says $2.55$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should be $\ln(1)$. Also, the Taylor approximation should be $P_2(x)=f(x_0)+f^{\prime}(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2$

Comment: Your solution is more reasonable - 1.3 is smaller than $e$, so $\ln(1.3)<\ln(e)=1$

Comment: Well, elementary use of a calculator shows ln(1.3) is roughly .26,  so I suspect your book is wrong, unless there's an order of magnitude off...plus it has to be much less than 1, due to Miel's comment

Comment: Your book probably should say $0.255$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, $\ln 1.3 \approx 0.262$ so you are much closer than the book.  The coefficient on the second term should be $-\frac 12$ because you lost the $\frac 1{2!}$ in the Taylor series.  You book is badly wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The 2nd degree Taylor polynomial for $f(x)=\ln x$ at $x=1$ is
$$
T_2(x)=0+(x-1)-{1\over 2}(x-1)^2,
$$
and
$$
T_2(x)\approx \ln x\text{ when }x\approx 1
$$
yields the approximation
$$
\ln(1.3)\approx T_2(1.3)=(1.3-1)-{1\over 2}(1.3-1)^2=\color{blue}{0.255}.
$$
Looks like your book just put the decimal in the wrong place.